# Distance calculation in wraparound hexagonal map

Tags: java, dictionary, distance, hexagonal-tiles

So I'm trying to get the basic calculations for an hexagonal tiled map. I'm using a rhombus style map as shown in this classic gem (check the "rhombus" option):

https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#map-storage

In my maps, R and Q are not necessarily the same, that is to say, the map can be "rectangular". Since the map wraps both in R and Q, there are many possible correct distances, of which I'm interested in finding the shortest.

E.g. distance from (0, 0) to (4, 2) is 6 if you go (0, 0) - (1, 0) - (2, 0) - (3, 0) - (4, 0) - (4, 1) - (4, 2), but it is 2 if you go (4, 2) - (5, 1) - (6, 0)=(0, 0)

So I got this code which calculates this wrapped distance correctly:

```
public static Integer distance(HexCubeCoord origin, HexCubeCoord destination) {
    // Normalize destination taking origin to (0, 0)
    Integer dR = destination.getGridR() - origin.getGridR();
    Integer dC = destination.getGridC() - origin.getGridC();
    // Wrap normalized distance
    HexCubeCoord normDest = new HexCubeCoord(HexCalculator.wrapR(dR), HexCalculator.wrapC(dC));
    // Calculate distances to (0, 0) and the other three mirror origins
    Integer d0 = simpleDistance(new HexCubeCoord(0, 0), normDest);
    Integer d1 = simpleDistance(new HexCubeCoord(0, HexGridData.getColCount()), normDest);
    Integer d2 = simpleDistance(new HexCubeCoord(HexGridData.getRowCount(), 0), normDest);
    Integer d3 = simpleDistance(new HexCubeCoord(HexGridData.getRowCount(), HexGridData.getColCount()), normDest);
    // Return the min of those four distances
    return Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(d0, d1), d2), d3);
}

public static Integer simpleDistance(HexCubeCoord origin, HexCubeCoord destination) {
    Integer dR = destination.getGridR() - origin.getGridR();
    Integer dC = destination.getGridC() - origin.getGridC();
    Integer dZ = - dC - dR;
    return Math.max(Math.max(Math.abs(dR), Math.abs(dC)), Math.abs(dZ));
}
```

Now, I will use distance calculation A LOT, and I would like it to be simpler. I've spent a lot of time already trying to reduce the amount of operations required, specially I would like to avoid calculating the distances to the four mirror origins to get the minimum of those afterwards.

I'm not asking for obvious optimizations like avoiding instantiating new objects, those I can figure out later. Is there any math wizardry I can use to make this algorithm simpler ?

Comment: Did you do a web search on "distance on a hexagonal grid"? Did any of the (many) links provide any help?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using `Integer` instead of `int`? You keep boxing the values, for no reason whatsoever. Use `int`, not `Integer`.

Comment: Yes, of course, distance on a hexagonal grid is explained everywhere and is exactly what my method simpleDistance() calculates. That distance is always correct, but it is not always the shortest possible in a wraparound map.

Comment: @Andreas: as I said, those optimizations I will figure out later, but thanks you very much for the help, I'll take it into account.

Comment: I believe the search term you are lacking is "toroidal hexagonal grid" (assuming it wraps left-to-right and top-to-bottom).  Topologically that shape is a toroid (think "doughnut").

Comment: Here's a C-language implementation you might be able to adapt: https://github.com/r-barnes/grid_engine

Comment: @Jim Garrison: thanks, but that code doesn't has any distance calculation whatsoever. I have already solved the issue of "walking" steps in any hex direction in a wrapped fashion.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: your search terms directed me to this page which offers some hope:  https://blog.demofox.org/2017/10/01/calculating-the-distance-between-points-in-wrap-around-toroidal-space/   It will take some work to see if this approach works in a hexagonal grid, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work and time, I finally came upon a distance calculation that seems to work for all my test cases.

I hope it is fine to answer to my own question, I post the resulting distance calculation in a wraparound hexagonal map, in case anybody else finds it interesting.

```
public static Integer distance(HexCubeCoord origin, HexCubeCoord destination) {
    // Normalize destination taking origin to (0, 0)
    Integer dR = destination.getGridR() - origin.getGridR();
    Integer dC = destination.getGridC() - origin.getGridC();
    // Wrap normalized distance to get closer to (0, 0)
    // Wrap c-wise
    if (Math.abs(dC) >= HexGridData.getColCount() / 2) {
        dC = (HexGridData.getColCount() - Math.abs(dC)) * (- Integer.signum(dC));
    }
    // Wrap r-wise
    if (Math.abs(dR) >= (HexGridData.getRowCount() / 2) - Math.floor(dC / 2)) {
        dR = (HexGridData.getRowCount() - Math.abs(dR)) * (- Integer.signum(dR));
    }
    Integer dZ = (- dC - dR);
    // Calculate distance in the usual form
    return Math.max(Math.max(Math.abs(dR), Math.abs(dC)), Math.abs(dZ));
}
```

It starts from the method outlined in https://blog.demofox.org/2017/10/01/calculating-the-distance-between-points-in-wrap-around-toroidal-space/, but then when wrapping r-wise, I add the "- Math.floor(dC / 2)" part to compensate for the assimetry of the grid over the (+, +) --- (-, -) diagonal.

EDIT (Jan '19):

I've found the solution provided doesn't work in some corner cases.

After some time I took on this issue again, and after A LOT of trying, I've found that the problem of calculating the distances in a wraparound hexagonal map becomes trivial if you use offset coordinates instead of axial or cube. The only caveat is that the number of rows or columns, whichever you decide to make offset, must be even, so that the map wraps properly.